# How to drop a table with foreign key constraint in SQL Server

Tags: azure-sql-database, sql-server-2016, azure-sql

I would like to drop a table with foreign key constraint and re-create the same table (with all the relationships) and with additional data (which I have from “Generate Scripts…”)

How can I do it? I'm using an Azure SQL Server.

If I disable the constraint, truncate the table, insert new data, and re-enable it? Will this work?

Any leads, please? Thanks.

Comment: Why not truncate instead?

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways is to create a `.sqlproj`. Inside this, you can create the tables, stored procedures, indexes, data population, and much more. The deployment from `.sqlproj` will take care of any changes you do to the data store. Please refer to the links below.

URL:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/azure-sqldb?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15